Нужна ссылка для отправки через Telegram API
Делаю на Python простую прогу для управления ботами в Telegram. Нужна ссылка для того, чтобы отправлять сообщения от лица бота пользователям по юзернейму (естественно тем, которые уже запустили бота), уже есть ссылка для отправки пользователю сообщения, имея его ID (ссылка - https://api.telegram.org/bot{API}/sendMesaage?chat_id={ID}&text={text}). Но нужно отправлять по юзернейму, не все же умеют проверять ID. Киньте, пожалуйста, ссылку URL, при открытии которой отправляется сообщение, либо ссылку, которая, имея юзернейм пользователя возвращает его личный ID. Если что, саму ссылку я встрою сам, главное без всяких доп модулей по типу telethon, цель - написать пресный код без посторонних библиотек.
